# Reduce size of mp4 video

Tags: windows-7, windows, mac, windows-vista, mp4

I have an mp4 file but it is huge and I want to reduce the size.
I can't use MovieMaker because it treats it as an audio (Vista).
If I rename to `mpg` it complains about codec missing.
How can I reduce the size and keep quality good?
I can use linux (e.g. from a Mac) if there is an appropriate tool or Windows 7

Comment: How big is the file right now, and how long is the runtime? Is it a raw file or has it already been encoded once. You can try re-encoding with Handbrake, but quality will suffer.

Comment: @CConard96:It is 1.5GB and is ~40mins. What is a "raw file"?

Comment: By raw, I meant uncompressed. Assuming the resolution is 1080p, that size seems about what I get when I record before I notice quality loss.

Comment: @CConard96:Yes uncompressed. How can I reduce the size?

Answer (score 0):

The best open source application I have found for taking an existing AVI or MP4 and compressing it is AVIDemux. Open the file, select the video output, and change to a smaller bitrate. You will probably need to read the man pages or a tutorial to learn your way around but it is worth it.